# expo notifications not working on standalone APK app SDK 38

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using expo SDK 38 with minimal workflow

My push notifications are working on the Expo client app but as soon as I build the APK, it doesn't work.

I have included google-services.json and also sent key using

expo push:android:upload --api-key